# Custom UITableViewCell without storyboard not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

UPDATE WITH ANSWER

I can use the textlabel property of the cell, i can set attributes to my custom labels and print the value (with the print after the switch), but i cannot get anything custom to display, not the background color, not the value, not anything.

Please note that i don't use storyboard at all for this, and the two classes are inside the same file (tried using two separate files, doesn't change anything so it is not related to my issue).

If anyone got an idea of what the issue is here and could point me to the right direction it would be great.

```
class DayPickerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    self.tableView.registerClass(DayPickerTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false
    self.tableView.bounces = false
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 8
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DayPickerTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = "test"
    switch indexPath.row {

    case 0:
        cell.dayModeLabel.text = "DAY"
        break
    case 1:
        cell.dayModeLabel.text = "WEEK"
        break
    case 2:
        cell.dayModeLabel.text = "WORK WEEK"

        break
    case 3:
        cell.dayModeLabel.text = "WEEK-END"

        break
    case 4:
        cell.dayModeLabel.text = "MONTH"

        break
    case 5:
        cell.dayModeLabel.text = "YEAR"

        break
    case 6:
        cell.dayModeLabel.text = "ALL HISTORY"

        break
    case 7:
        cell.dayModeLabel.text = "CUSTOM"

        break
    default: break
    }
    print(cell.dayModeLabel.text)
    return cell
}

}

class DayPickerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var imgDayPicker = UIImageView()
var dayModeLabel = UILabel()
var dayDisplayLabel = UILabel()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    imgDayPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dayModeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dayDisplayLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    imgDayPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    dayModeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    dayDisplayLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.contentView.addSubview(imgDayPicker)
    self.contentView.addSubview(dayModeLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(dayDisplayLabel)

    let viewsDict = [
        "image" : imgDayPicker,
        "mode" : dayModeLabel,
        "day" : dayDisplayLabel,
    ]

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[image(50)][mode(==day)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

in order for the code to work, replace the awake from nib method with this :

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    imgDayPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dayModeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dayDisplayLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    imgDayPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    dayModeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    dayDisplayLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.contentView.addSubview(imgDayPicker)
    self.contentView.addSubview(dayModeLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(dayDisplayLabel)

    let viewsDict = [
        "image" : imgDayPicker,
        "mode" : dayModeLabel,
        "day" : dayDisplayLabel,
    ]

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[image(50)][mode(==day)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Comment: Are you getting cells back in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: maybe `awakeFromNib` isnt being called. put a log in it or try overriding initWithCoder

Comment: Yes i get the cell back, like i said i can print stuff, change colors, but i do not see anything coming from the custom part of the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storyboard/xib loader sends `awakeFromNib`. Since you're not using a storyboard or xib, nothing is sending `awakeFromNib` to the cell, so that code never runs.

You could just call `cell.awakeFromNib()`, although that would be misleading. I would move the code into `init`.

You also need more constraints on the subviews.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, wasn't aware that awakefromnib was expecting a storyboard...

Proper coding is better than weird patches, gonna try to implement init.

Comment: Working like a charm, thanks, and indeed it seems that i will need a few more constraints.